# How to make the output `1` when the input is "1200" and "1300"?

Tags: c, integer, cs50

When running this code and putting 1200 for `startn` and 1300 for `endn`, the output is `Years:0`. Where to pass the given test it should be `Years:1`. Note that the code runs without errors and works with other numbers.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>



int main(void)
{
    int startn;
    int endn;

    do
    {
    startn = get_int("what should the starting number of llamas be?\n");
    endn = get_int("what should the ending number of llamas be?\n");
    }
    while (startn < 9 || endn < startn);


    float total = (startn + startn/3 - startn/4);
    float finalTotal = total;
    int n=0;
    
    
    while (finalTotal<endn)
    {
        finalTotal = (finalTotal + finalTotal/3 - finalTotal/4);
        n++;
    }


    printf("Years: %i\n", n);
}
```

The purpose of the code is to calculate the number of years needed to reach the given end population of llamas `endn` and starting from the given population of llamas. While doing that, we add born llamas `+ finalTotal/3` and remove died llamas `- finalTotal/4`. And then saving the total number in `finalTotal`

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? You have given us one example but have not told us the overall requirements.

Comment: I will edit it.

Comment: Highly suspicious: Relying on `float` to be precise to the integer level. Having identical code using division that runs on `int` (which will truncate) and `float` (which won't).

Comment: what do you suggest to do?

Comment: What should be the answer for start 1200 and end 1301?

Comment: `Year: 1`
The needed output for my problem

Answer (score 1):

If you initialize `finalTotal` with `startn`, then it will work. Your code look like the following:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>



int main(void)
{
    int startn;
    int endn;

    do
    {
    startn = get_int("what should the starting number of llamas be?\n");
    endn = get_int("what should the ending number of llamas be?\n");
    }
    while (startn < 9 || endn < startn);

    float finalTotal = startn;
    int n=0;

    while (finalTotal<endn)
    {
        finalTotal = finalTotal + (int)(finalTotal/3) - (int)(finalTotal/4);
        n++;
    }

    printf("Years: %i\n", n);
}
```

You computed the first year manually, so it never stepped in the last `while` .

Also you should count the llamas as integers too, instead of float.
After a bit refactor, and more appropriate variable names the code looks like the following:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int start_num;
    int end_num;

    do
    {
        start_num = get_int("what should the starting number of llamas be?\n");
        end_num = get_int("what should the ending number of llamas be?\n");
    }
    while (start_num < 9 || end_num < start_num);

    int current_num = start_num;
    int years = 0;

    while (current_num < end_num)
    {
        int new_borns = current_num / 3;
        int deaths = current_num / 4;
        current_num = current_num + new_borns - deaths;
        years++;
    }

    printf("Years: %i\n", years);
}
```

Comment: Like your code. But you manually computed the first year's progress, still initialized `n` as `0` like nothing happened. If you delete that part from your code, and simply start from `startn` and set the `n` to `0` then it works correctly

Comment: There is a new problem that occurs... as the starting number is "100" the output is 116 while it should be 115

Comment: Use `double` instead of `float`, it is more precise.

Comment: Same problem when using `double`.

Comment: What is the endn in the new case?

Comment: endn in this case is 1000000.

Comment: Yeah, that... The number of the llamas are always integers, because only a whole llama can born or die. So the `finalTotal/3` and the `finalTotal/4` should be casted to `int`. I corrected the code, now it works fine.

Comment: @erdelyia: It might make sense to *round* rather than truncate, so, for example, with five llamas you get two newborns and one death. Even then, `int` based math will have some issues for small numbers; if you start with less eight llamas, then you'll quickly reach a steady state where births and deaths cancel out, keeping the numbers constant, even if you use "more accurate" rounding over truncation.